# How to stay logged in in ASP.NET using PhoneGap and inAppBrowser plugin after the app is closed?

Tags: asp.net, cordova

i'm developing an app using phonegap.
i'm using inappbrowser plugin to display my asp.net pages where my users login and get connected to my server.

how can i let the users login just once then the next time they open the app they get automatically connected without the need to login again?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can use localstorage to save credentials. But bad idea. Cause localstorage life cycle isn't good enough. Specially iPhone treats localstorage as temporary storage

2) You can use database like webSql to save the credentials in your app. Make a ASP service in your website to link up your app and website. Save the credentials at first time inside your app. In the second time check if credentials exists in your app database, if exists then log him in through that ASP service page without the knowledge of the app user.

There are the ways I could think of. I don't know if there any cache or session style exists in inAppBrowser. If exists may be others will help you with that.